KafkaJS throws Event Emitter memory leak warning
I recently implemented a Kafka in my NodeJS application using KafkaJS. It's all working fine, however often times from the consumer code following the warning printed on the terminal.
    MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 
11 connect listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Strangely this warning only prints in the Linux server where I deploy the application for the testing. This warning doesn't print in my Macbook localhost. This warning prints only in the consumer code.
FYI: Proudcer and Consumer codebase are deployed in two different servers.
Here's my complete kafka and consumer code.
Main kafka class
const GROUP_ID = getEnv().kafkaConfig.group_id;
export class KafkaService implements IQueueService {
    private kafka: Kafka;
    private producer: Producer;
    private consumer: Consumer;
    private topic: string;
    private assignedPartitions: number[] = [];
    private isRebalancing = false;
    private isProducer = false;

    constructor(topic: string, isProducer: boolean) {
       this.topic = topic;
       this.isProducer = isProducer;
    }

    async startService(): Promise<void>  {

        try {
            this.kafka = new Kafka({
                
                "clientId": "lkc-xxxx",
                "brokers": ["xxxxx.us-east1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092"],
                "ssl": true,
                "sasl": {
                    "mechanism": "plain",
                    "username": "xxxxxxx",
                    "password":
                        "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                },
                "connectionTimeout": 10000,
                "requestTimeout": 60000,
                "logLevel": 1,
                ...(this.isProducer && {createPartitioner: Partitioners.DefaultPartitioner}),
                ...({clientId: `${this.isProducer ? 'producer' : 'worker'}_${Date.now()}`})
            });
            this.producer = this.kafka.producer({
            });
            this.consumer = this.kafka.consumer({
                groupId: getEnv().kafkaConfig.group_id,
                partitionAssigners: [
                    await this.getPartitionAssigner()
                ],
                sessionTimeout: 60000,
                heartbeatInterval: 10000, // should be lower than sessionTimeout
            });
            await this.connect();
        } catch(error) {
            throw new AppError("Error initiating Kafka " + error.message)
        }
    
    }

    private async getPartitionAssigner(): Promise<PartitionAssigner> {

        const topic = this.topic;
        const userData = Buffer.from([]);
    
        const admin = this.kafka.admin();
        const meta = await admin.fetchTopicMetadata({ topics: [topic] });
    
        const numPartitions = meta.topics.filter(t => t.name === topic)[0].partitions.length;
    
        return ({ cluster }) => ({
            name: 'AssignedPartitionsAssigner',
            version: 1,
            async assign({ members }) {
    
              const segment = Math.ceil(numPartitions / members.length);
    
              const membersWithPartitions = members.map((member, index) => {
                return {
                  memberId: member.memberId,
                  memberAssignment: AssignerProtocol.MemberAssignment.encode({
                    version: this.version,
                    assignment: {
                      [topic]: new Array(segment).fill(0)
                        .map((_, i) => (index * segment) + i)
                        .filter((item, i) => Number(item) < numPartitions)
                    },
                    userData
                  })
                }
              });
              
              return membersWithPartitions;
            },
            protocol({ topics }) {
                return {
                    name: this.name,
                    metadata: AssignerProtocol.MemberMetadata.encode({
                        version: this.version,
                        topics,
                        userData,
                    })
                };
            }
        });
      }

    async connect(): Promise<void> {

        const topic = this.topic;
        try {

            if (this.isProducer) { 
                await this.producer.connect();
            } else {
                await this.consumer.connect();
            }

            const {
                GROUP_JOIN
              } = this.consumer.events;
          
              this.consumer.on(GROUP_JOIN, async e => {
                this.assignedPartitions = e.payload.memberAssignment[topic];
                this.isRebalancing = false;
                
                for (let partition of this.assignedPartitions) {
                  const lastOffset = await getRedis().get<string>(`kafka:${topic}-${GROUP_ID}-${partition}`);
                  
                  this.consumer.seek({ 
                    topic, 
                    partition: Number(partition), 
                    offset: lastOffset ? JSON.parse(lastOffset).offset : '0' 
                  });
                }
              });

        } catch (error) {
            getLogger().error(`Error connecting to Kafka: ${error.message}`);
            throw error;
        }
    }

    async disconnect(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            if (this.isProducer)
                await this.producer.disconnect();
            else 
                await this.consumer.disconnect();
        } catch (error) {
            getLogger().error(
                `Error disconnecting from Kafka: ${error.message}`
            );
            throw error;
        }
    }

    async produce(
        key: string | null,
        message: Buffer,
        uniqueId?: string
    ): Promise<void> {
        const topic = this.topic;
        try {
            await this.producer.send({
                topic,
                acks: 1, // update only the leader
                timeout: 6000, //milliseconds
                messages: [
                    {
                        key,
                        value: message,
                        headers: uniqueId ? {
                            message_id: uniqueId,
                        } : {}
                    },
                ],
            });
        } catch (error) {
            getLogger().error(
                `Error producing to Kafka topic ${topic}: ${error.message}`
            );
            throw error;
        }
    }

    async consume(
        callback: (message: any) => Promise<void>,
        avroType?: avro.Type
    ): Promise<void> {
        const topic = this.topic;

        if (!this.consumer) {
            throw new Error("Kafka consumer not initialized");
        }
      
        await this.consumer.subscribe({ topic: topic as string });
    
        const config: ConsumerRunConfig = {
        eachBatchAutoResolve: false,
        autoCommit: false,
        eachMessage: async ({ partition, message }) => {
            if(this.isRebalancing) return;
    
            try {

                const value = JSON.parse(
                        avroType.fromBuffer(message.value)
                );
                await callback(value)
                await this.storeConsumerOffsetInRedis(
                    this.topic, 
                    partition,
                    Number(message.offset) 
                )
    
               
                
            } catch (error) {
                if(isRebalancingError(error)){
                    this.isRebalancing = true;
                }

                getLogger().error(
                    `Error consuming from Kafka topic ${topic}: ${error.message}`
                );
                throw error;
            }
        },};
    
        this.consumer.run(config);
    }

    private async storeConsumerOffsetInRedis(topic:string, partition:number, offset: number) {
        await getRedis().set(
            `kafka:${topic}-${GROUP_ID}-${partition}`,
            JSON.stringify({
              topic,
              partition: partition,
              offset: (offset + 1).toString()
            })
          )
    }
}

}
Queue Service Wrapper
import { KafkaService } from '../kafka';
import { IQueueService } from '../QueueServiceInterface';
import avro from 'avsc';
import { ingestorAvroType } from '../avro/index';

export class QueueService implements IQueueService {
    private queueProvider: IQueueService;

    constructor(topic: string, isProducer: boolean) {
        this.queueProvider = new KafkaService(topic, isProducer);
    }

    async connect(): Promise<void> {
        await this.queueProvider.connect();
    }

    async disconnect(): Promise<void> {
        await this.queueProvider.disconnect();
    }

    async startService(): Promise<void> {
        await this.queueProvider.startService();
    }

    async produce(
        key: string | null,
        message: Object,
        uniqueId?: string
    ): Promise<void> {
        await this.queueProvider.produce(
            key,
            this.getAvroFileByTopic().toBuffer(message),
            uniqueId
        );
    }

    getAvroFileByTopic(): avro.Type {
        return ingestorAvroType;
    }

    async consume(
        callback: (message: any) => Promise<void>,
    ): Promise<void> {
        await this.queueProvider.consume(
            callback,
            this.getAvroFileByTopic()
        );
    }
}

Consumer Code:
const startConsumer = async () => {
    const env = getEnv();
    const { redis, mongo } = env;
    await initializeMongo(mongo);
    await initializeRedis(redis);
    const getService = (await import('./init/init')).getService;

    const ingestorQueueService = new QueueService(getEnv().kafkaConfig.topic.ingestor_data, false);
    await ingestorQueueService.startService();
    await ingestorQueueService.consume(
        async (data: IIngestorData) => {
            const service = getService(data.geo);
            try {
                const decoder: DeviceHandler | null = await getDeviceDecoderByProtocol(
                    data,
                    service,
                );
                console.log("CONSUMER :" + new Date(data.published_at).toISOString())
                await retryOperation(async () => {
                    await decoder.decodeConsumer(data.rawData);
                });
                console.log("CONSUMER 2 :" + new Date(data.published_at).toISOString())
            } catch (error) {
                getLogger().error(`Consumer failed : ${error.message}`);
                
            }                
        }
    );
    console.log('Ingestor Consumer Started');
};

startConsumer().catch((err) =>
    getLogger().error(`Error in worker ${cluster.worker.id}:`, err)
);

Package.json how I boot up the consumer
{
....
"scripts": {
...
        "serve-consumer": "node --trace-warnings --max-old-space-size=4096 dist/consumer.js",
...
}
}

Linux Server Info

2 Core CPU
4 GB Ram

I want to know, how can I get rid of this Event Emitter warning? and leaving this warning will it impact the consumer service?
Thanks in advance.
